# IF in WHERE mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table.

[image]

In MySql I want select this user IF `key` column do not have `custom` row AND IF `key` column have `custom` row -> `value` column = `yes`.

This is my query, but it do not work:

```
where `value` = if(`key` = 'custom', 'yes', '')
```

Comment: _"In MySql I want"_ - then go and do it! What hinders you?

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you want to acheive

Comment: Have you tried to express this logic in a `WHERE` clause?  What combination of `AND` and `OR` clauses are you attempting?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: thought about normalizing your table?

Comment: Bit of a side note here: you're using a [mysql reserved](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) word (being `key`) and you should try and stay away from that, since it requires the column name to be escaped (Edit: to which you have escaped it, seeing the edit). Btw, have you tried resolving this yourself first? It shouldn't be too hard, figuring that you can use (different) [logical operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html).

Comment: See my update..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification for the query isn't clear, in that it's open to several different interpretations.

I'm thinking the question is about how to return a particular result, not really about using an `IF()` function in the `WHERE` clause. (None of the SQL below uses  an `IF()` function in a `WHERE` clause.)

---

Here's one possible interpretation of the specification:

By "select this user", we'll take that to mean we want to return a single copy of the `user_id` column.

By "IF key column do not have custom row", we'll take that to mean that there does not exist such a row for this user_id, then return this user_id. If such a row does exist, then do not return the user.

By "AND IF key column have custom row -> value column = yes.", we'll take that to mean to return this user_id if there is a row for this user_id that matches the condition.

Based on that interpretation, here's an approach to satisfying the specification using conditional aggregation:

```
 SELECT t.user_id
   FROM this_table t 
  GROUP
     BY t.user_id
 HAVING SUM(1) = SUM(IF(t.key='custom',IF(t.value='yes',1,0),1))
```

The expression inside the SUM() aggregate gets evaluated for each row. That expression is designed to return either a 1 or a 0, depending on whether the row matches the specified conditions. The `SUM()` aggregate totals up those 1s and 0s. And then we compare the result to the total number of rows. That tells us if a "matching" row exists or not.

The counts are by user_id, as identified in the `GROUP BY` clause.

The MySQL `IF()` function can be replace with a more portable ANSI `CASE` expression

```
 HAVING SUM(1) = SUM(CASE
                     WHEN t.key = 'custom' 
                     THEN CASE 
                          WHEN t.value = 'yes' 
                          THEN 1 
                          ELSE 0 
                          END
                     ELSE 1
                     END
                 )
```

---

If the intent is to return all of the detail rows for a user, but excluding all user_id that meet the specification, we could use an EXISTS correlated subquery:

```
 SELECT t.user_id
      , t.key
      , t.value
   FROM this_table t
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                       FROM this_table r
                      WHERE r.user_id = t.user_id 
                        AND r.key     = 'custom'
                   )
     OR EXISTS     ( SELECT 1
                       FROM this_table q
                      WHERE q.user_id = t.user_id 
                        AND q.key     = 'custom'
                        AND q.value   = 'yes'
                   )
```

Comment: GROUP BY t.user_id HAVING SUM(1) =SUM(IF(t.key='custom',IF(t.value='yes',1,0),1)) is working fine, thank so much!

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following statement which select any row has `key` not equal `'custom'` or equal `'custom'` and `value` equal `'yes'`

```
Select * from tableName where `key`<> 'custom' or  (`key` = 'custom' and  `value` = 'yes')
```

Comment: same result as  `where not (t.key = 'custom' and not ( t.value <=> 'yes' ) )`

Comment: Thanks, but it will not working, because it will select others rows.